# how to pass enum value into structure

Tags: c, gcc, enums, structure

My problem is I need to pass value from argument (instType, typ1, *op1...) to the structure type tInst.

I'm sure it's a trivial problem but I've spent about 3 hours of my time working on it.

GCC returns segmentation fault 11.

my .h file

```
typedef enum tInstCode {

    I_ADD=0, // (dest, addr, addr) +
    I_SUB, // (dest, addr, addr) -
    I_MUL, // (dest, addr, addr) *
    I_DIV, // (dest, addr, addr) /

} tInstCode;



typedef enum TypeI{
    INT=0,  
    DOUBLE, 
    STRING
} TypeI;


typedef struct iOperand
{
    TypeI type; 
    void *content; 
} iOperand;

typedef struct tInst 
{
    tInstCode instType; 
    iOperand *op1; 
    iOperand *op2; 
    iOperand *res; 
} tInst;

typedef struct ListItem 
{
    tInst Instruction;
    struct ListItem *NextItem;
} tListItem;
```

my main file :

```
void generateInstruction(tInstCode instType, TypeI typ1,  void *op1, TypeI typ2, void *op2, TypeI typ3, iOperand *op3 )

{

   tListOfInstr list;
   listInit(&list);  //list defined in another file
   tInst* I;

   I->instType = instType;
   I->op1->type = typ1;


   I->op1->content = op1;

   I->op2 -> type = typ2;
   I->op2 -> content = op2;

   I->res -> type = typ3;
   I->res -> content = op3;
   listInsertLast(&list, *I);

}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int a;      
  a=8;
  int *b;      
  b = &a; 

  int c;       
  c=1;
  int *d;      
  d = &c; 

  generateInstruction(0, DOUBLE, *b, INT, *d, INT, NULL);


}
```

Comment: You should be getting a warning about converting an `int` to a `void*` when passing `*b` and `*d` to `generateInstruction`.

Answer (score 1):

```
tInst* I;

I->instType = instType;
```

You're not allocating memory for `I`.

As it currently is `I` is just a pointer with a (potentially) random value. Use `malloc` to get a suitable address with free memory.

This could be done like this:

```
tInst* I;
I = malloc(sizeof(tInst));
I->op1 = malloc(sizeof(iOperand));
I->op2 = malloc(sizeof(iOperand));
I->res = malloc(sizeof(iOperand));
```

Though keep in mind that `malloc` can fail, so you want to check the return value for NULL.

Comment: may I know what arguments should i pass to malloc? Now I can pass instType but the rest still doesn't work. I tried this : `tInst* I = malloc(sizeof(struct tInst));` which seems to be wrong. Maybe the error is somewhere else.

Comment: Your call `generateInstruction(0, DOUBLE, *b, INT, *d, INT, NULL)` is also wrong. The `*b` and `*d` should be `b` and `d` respectively, or you could just use `&a` and `&c` instead of `b` and `d`. Presumably, the `0` should be `I_ADD` as well.